# C# application to query Search Server Express 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, search-server-2010

I have been playing around with Search Server Express 2010 and have built up a little windows application in C# to attempt to query the server and return some results. Whenever i attempt to run the query i receive the error "The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service."

My query is below. I have also tried a query of type MSSQLFT.

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>
   <Query>
  <SupportedFormats>
     <Format revision='1'> urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format>
  </SupportedFormats>
  <Context>
     <QueryText language='en' type='FQL'>
     </QueryText>
  </Context>
  <ResultProvider>FASTSearch</ResultProvider>
  <Range>
     <Count>10</Count>
  </Range>
   </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

Neither of my query attempts have worked and both got the same error and nothing i am searching for is assisting with a solution.

I have deliberately broke it in other ways by taking the search server offline, creating an error in the search, etc. and they all give me different errors, so i am thinking the query does actually reach the server ok! (Also i am sure i have permissions correct)

Does anyone have any thoughts? Am i actually even able to search the express version of search server in this manner?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok, simple, as it turns out FQL wont work with 2010 express, and is obvious now i think about it (lack of initial research i guess). When i used MSSQLFT query type i accidentally left the

```
<ResultsProvider>FastSearch</ResultsProvider>
```

line in there. This was causing the error i was getting.

The query that worked for me was

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>
<Query>
<SupportedFormats>
<Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response</Format>
</SupportedFormats>
<Context>
<QueryText language='en' type='MSSQLFT'>
SELECT Filename, Title, FileExtension, Path from Scope()
</QueryText>
</Context>
<Range>
<Count>10</Count>
</Range>
</Query>
</QueryPacket>
```